# How to set the location of a tap

Tags: sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I want to set this game up so that when the user taps a specific point on the screen it dispenses a **SKSpriteNode** from the location. So what I've set up is this inside the touches began method:

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    score = score + 1;

    cat = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"cat.png"] size:CGSizeMake(35, 35)];
    cat.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+120);

    [self addChild:cat];
}
```

Which works fine and adds the node to any where the touch occurred.

I want it only to be added when the user touches a specific location, so I tried setting this up:

```
for (touch locationInNode:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) {
    score = score + 1;

    cat = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"cat.png"] size:CGSizeMake(35, 35)];
    cat.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+120);

    [self addChild:cat];
}
```

But it didn't work and told me I needed a square bracket ] for some reason.

**How can I set it up so it only spawns if the user touches the middle of the screen?**

Comment: locationInNode is a method. You need to use square brackets around it. There are many other problems here however. Do you know how a for loop works?

Comment: Not entirely, the for loop is a piece of code I stole from the template for a SpriteKit project (when the user taps it spawns a spaceship) @CrimsonChris

Comment: I have examined the same sample project myself. Trust me when I tell you that if this is the first time you've seen a for loop, you aren't going to get very far. I recommend reading up on beginners Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: I'll definitely check it out. Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do that I should look up? Maybe an if statement? @CrimsonChris

Comment: You probably want an if conditional within the loop to test if the toothed location is within some bounds.

Comment: I tried setting something like that up but it didn't seem to want to work either @CrimsonChris

Comment: Post the code you used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53922/discussion-between-liam-stockhomme-and-crimsonchris)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
        // Add your logic to check the specific location 
        // if( CGPointEqualToPoint (positionInScene, yourSpecificPosition)

        // Render Cat


  }
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(crate.frame, location)) {
            score = score + 1;

   cat = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"cat.png"] size:CGSizeMake(35, 35)];
    cat.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+120);

    [self addChild:cat];
        }
    }
```